# python から microsoft sql server で　ＤＢへのアクセス　は可能でしょうか？

Tags: python, sql-server

pythonの初級者です。
python+sqliteで社内サーバーからCSVファイル越しにデータを取得してデータ分析しております。CSVファイル化する作業が短い時間ながらも煩わしく感じます。
python+microsoft sqlserverで直接データ取得をしたいですが、技術的にこのようなことは可能なのでしょうか？
WEBや書籍等で調査してみると、python+sqliteやpython+mysqlは多いようですが、
python+sql serverはあまり見かけません。

ご指導いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

可能ですよ。[pymssql](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/)を使えばいいと思います。ググればたくさん情報でてきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調査不足でした。キーワードが分かったので勉強します。